# How to connect switches to PWB on IP69K sealed pannel without wiring harnesses while still allowing easy separation of board and panel?

Tags: switches, button, environmental-sealing

I am working on a project that has a panel that has several push-buttons, and rocker-switches on it.  The buttons/switches connect to a PWB that sits behind the panel.  The buttons/switches/panel need to be sealed.  The usual method is to use sealed panel mount switches/buttons and connect them to the PWB via a wiring harness.

There is a mechanical engineer who is in charge of the project and they insist on not having a harness.  They are proposing mounting the switches to the panel and then soldering the board to the panel.
[image]

There are many problems with this approach.

1. Our manufacturing plant and test group will hate us forever for making them build this.
2. Attaching the PWB to the panel will likely have to be done by hand since we cant put the whole panel assembly in the selective solder machines.  This increases the amount of manual labor required to build the boards.
3. Once we test the seal on the panel we can't open it without re-testing.  This means that the PWB must be soldered to the switches before we leak test.  If any leaks are found, fixing them requires desoldering the PWB from the switches, which is a lot of work.
4. The board cannot be fully tested until its soldered to the panel.  And if problems are found, we are again faced with desoldering the PWB from the switches.
5. We are going to be building thousands of these boards and doing 100% testing, so making them easy to build and test is a priority.

**Does anyone know a solution to this problem that allows access to the switches/buttons while keeping the panel sealed, without using a wiring harness while still allowing easy separation of the panel and PWB?**

I know of some theoretical possibilities, but I don't know where to get them, or if anyone actually makes them.

1. Use a rubber sealing boot over the buttons.  The buttons are no longer directly connected to the panel so there is no problem just soldering them to the board.  There are some products such as APM Hex Seal, but the mechanical engineer is resistant to this solution because he feels the boots wont be durable.  In the past we have had torn sealing boots if a user steps on the panel with their own boot.  Also there does not appear to be an option for a boot for a rocker switch.

[image]

2. Use sealed panel mount switches/buttons that have a matching PWB mount plug.  I am not aware of anyone who makes this (but it would be ideal).

[image]

3. Use a sealed panel mount plunger and then use it to actuate a standard PWB mount button.  This is similar to using a boot, but the plunger is not rubber and therefore can be much more durable.  I am not aware of anyone who makes such a plunger.  Also I am not sure how this would work for a rocker switch.

[image]

NOTE:  We prefer sealing to IP69K is preferable due to how the equipment will be cleaned.  But lower levels of sealing (at least as good as IP68) would be considered.

NOTE:  I show three buttons in the pictures for simplicity, but in reality there are many more buttons and rocker switches attached the same way.

Comment: Have you considered ring magnets on the plungers and reed relay ampules? For the IP69K spec? Just curious.

Comment: @jonk I did not consider using magnets.  But at the time, I didn't know where to get sealed plungers to even mount the magnets to.  Unless you are proposing that the magnets would just work through the aluminum frame without any hole through the frame.  That could be a good idea if I could find such plungers.

Comment: It's been a long time -- almost a year now. Where are you at now? I think you have, for the first time, mentioned an aluminum frame. Did I miss something beforehand? Not that it matters. I was mostly wanting to know if you had considered using your imagination with the idea of a ring magnet and a reed glass ampule, or not. I didn't mean to imply I had a solution in mind. Just wondering, is all. That said, I'm still stuck on a comment (didn't really read it until now) about the case when a *"user steps on the panel with their own boot."* I'd like to know more about this. I'm very curious.

Comment: I'm not a mechanical engineer. You have one who is very vested in what's going on. So, if I were in your shoes, I'd probably walk over and toss down some existing pieces for them to examine and consider and some existing products using them (I have such a keyboard made by Cherry under contract to Tektronix when Cherry hadn't yet been bought up.) But as I said, I never considered the idea that users would walk, with full body weight, on your panel. That makes me very cautious about saying anything at all until I hear a great deal more about that situation.

Comment: @jonk Well its over by now, but it was for a vehicle application for harsh environments and where people in heavy boots might be expected to step on basically any of the equipment or cabling.  In any case I always appreciate your comments and suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Appreciated.